# Suggestion for books in Pertubation theory with an emphasis on the theory

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

As the title suggest I am looking for another good coverage of the theory of Pertubation theory.
Currently I am working through Murodock's book: Pertubations: Theory and Methods.

But I am rest assure that the field should have more theory than what is covered in Murdock's, also open theorywise problems are fine by me.

Most books that i found only have technical examples without looking at the theory, I am sure there are technical theorywise books in this field but not sure where to look.

I am asking for regular and singular pertubations, also if you have theoretical books on pertubation theory of PDEs, since Murdock's only deals mainly on ODEs and algebraic polynomials.

Thanks!

Comment: Tosio Kato. Perturbation theory for linear operators.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko does it deal with pertubation theory in PDEs?

Comment: It deals with "theory", as you said. With perturbation theory for linear operators. Linear operators can be differential or not, differential operators can be ordinary or partial. It begins with a large chapter of perturbation of finite dimensional operators.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will dive in; seems like a solid foundation for me, theorywise.